# Maintaining CircleCI on several repository

Tags: circleci-2.0

We have several repositories on Github and just recently explored to integrate it our continuous integration/deployment to CircleCI. The thing is, every time we update something on .circleci directory of a certain repository, we need to do the same for the others. Is there a way to have it like a dependency so all our repository can just fetch from that?